# Strange behavior of cells in table view on iphone, change if one cause change in another

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

My app has a list from server, everytime when scrolls goes down i sends request for new data and reloads it. I recives 10 cells.  This work just fine.

But the problem is, if i change value for example in 1 cell, it changes in cell 8, 15 and so on.

Data is the class, where i get the information from server to display in cells.
getDataAt is the method in my cell class, which puts values into cell.

In numberOfRowsInSection im checking if list is complete, table view displays addiotional cell to load more rows, if list is incomplete it means that there is no more rows to display and this cell won't display.

Code :

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row < [self.list size])
     {

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

        self.cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        Data* data = [self.list getDataAt:indexPath.row];

        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
        cell.delegate = self;
        [cell setCell:data];


        return  _cell;

    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  {

return [self.list size] + (self.list.complete ? 0 : 1);

}
```

What I've found so far is that when i scroll up and down, indexPath gets confused and when he adds 10 cells more, it takes indexPath.row of previous cells.

Comment: show code for numberofrowsinSection.

Comment: How you change the value of data in cells?

Comment: i have button plus and minus, and label which display curent value

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  
    return [self.articleList size] + (self.articleList.complete ? 0 : 1);
    
}

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {   
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)  
   {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (indexPath.row < [self.list size]) 
     {
        Data* data = [self.list getDataAt:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
        [cell setCell:data];
     }

   return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you don't need to check that row index is out of bounds - instead you should return properly value in numberOfRowsInSection method. 
And what you return if it (indexPath.row < [self.list size]) is wrong? if you return nil - it will crash.

Also, it may be an error here:
you are using different variables for accessing cell: 'cell' and '_cell'. 
And there is no need to save last cell in local variable.

I'm assume that you register your reusable cell's class (or nib) for table view earlier.

Try something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.delegate = self;
    Data* data = [self.list getDataAt:indexPath.row];
    [cell setCell:data];
    return  cell;

}

– tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.list size];
}
```

Comment: Im doing it, and yes, i registered in in viewDidLoad
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { return [self.articleList size] + (self.articleList.complete ? 0 : 1); }

this is my code, im checking if list has page size of 10, if yes I add extra cell which is responsible for load more rows, if is less than 10, this cell won't display

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the cell is not assigning efficiently.
u need to implement the following as your own way:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    [self setCell:cell atIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else{
    [self reuseCell:cell atIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And the setCell:atIndex: method will be following:

```
setCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell atIndex:(int)index{
Data* data = [self.list getDataAt:index];
[cell setCell:data];
}
```

Suppose you have a label on your cell, your are adding the label on the cell on the setCell.

```
(void)setCell:(Data*)data{
label.text = @"text from data";
[cell addSubView:label];//this is the important part, you are adding the label on cell as a subview
//doing other stuff
}
```

Now the reuseCell method will be similar as following(assuming you have a label on your cell, on this time u need to reset the label, not assigning or adding the label to your cell):

```
reuseCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell atIndex:(int)index{
Data* data = [self.list getDataAt:index];
cell.label.text = @"text from data";//here your are modifying the label, not adding the label as a subView of the cell
//doing other stuff
}
```

And finally you need not to check the "indexPath.row < [self.list size]", because u are already saying the total number of cell on the "- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section".

I cloud describe it more clearly if you can provide the details of "setCell:" method and also why using cell as a property.